# What does "nanode" mean? What are its grammatical rules?

Tags: grammar, particles

What's the meaning of this sentence and what does なので mean here? If possible, I would like to know the grammatical rules of なので as well.

> 英語と日本語なので私にとっても良い勉強になります。

Comment: Do you know what ので means?

Comment: What's your exact problem? You really haven't seen なので at all and you are asking about it without consulting a dictionary? Or you know it but have difficulty finding the reasonable interpretation? Then what's the context?

Comment: yes i have googled it but i found only that "nanode"means "since" in english and it didnt make sense to me

Answer (score 12):

> 英語{えいご}と日本語{にほんご}なので私{わたし}にとっても良{い}い勉強{べんきょう}になります。

- Because *it* is Japanese and English it is very useful / helpful to me.
- It's really good for my studies because *it* is (in) English and Japanese.

## Usage of [ので・なので](http://www.renshuu.org/index.php?page=grammar/individual&id=100)

> Similar to [から](http://japanese.about.com/library/blqow35.htm), it is used to express reason or cause. Use **な** when following a noun or word that functions as a noun.

- 冬{ふゆ}**なので**花{はな}は咲{さ}いてない。 There are no flowers (blooming) **because** it's / of winter.
- 下手{へた}**なので**やめた方{ほう}がいいかな？ I wonder if I should quit *it* **because** I am not good at it.
- もう遅{おそ}い**ので**帰{かえ}ろうね。 It's (already) late, **so** let's go home (friendly).
- [More examples.](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7)

Answer (score 10):

Like から, it can mean "so", "therefore", "since", "because", but ので　is technically supposed to be used for highlighting a cause-and-effect relationship, while から is for subjectively presenting a cause or a reason.

Either way, ので feels more polite, so it is often the one used when you are gently expressing a reason, asking for permission, when making an excuse, or other similar situations.

The な is added when following **nouns** and **na adjectives**, and what it's doing is essentially replacing a だ.

Here's an example of that:

> ここは駐車禁止**な**ので車を止めてはいけません。
>
> ここは駐車禁止**だ**から車を止めてはいけません。