# (noun) + な versus (verb) + な

Tags: verbs, nouns, negation

Actually, I want I'm figuring out a specific sentence, which is 「暇なので相手して。」And I thought that it means "I am bored because of my companion."

- 暇 [hima] - "leisure" / "fun"
- な [na] - Negative imperative. Meaning "himana" means "not fun"
- ので [node] - "because"
- 相手 [aite] - "companion" or someone with me
- して [shite] - "I am doing" or current state

But according to http://www.japanesefile.com/Adjectives/hima_na_1.html
"hima na" means "to have free time"

Comment: 「暇なので相手して。」 means "Play with me because I have nothing to do." But I am still figuring why for future use.

Comment: ので acts on the clause before, not the clause after, so it's "because I have free time ..." . That な is not the negative imperative. Maybe this link helps: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19591/what-does-nanode-mean-what-are-its-grammatical-rules

Comment: ok, I already know that "nanode" is used as "because" / "since" thanks for the link. But is there any reason why「な」 is not the negative imperative in my sentence?

Comment: Because 暇 is a na-adjective not a verb. The negative imperative can only come after a verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

暇 acts as an adjective here, which explains the な which is basically the 連体形 of the 活用語尾 (conjugative suffix).
暇 can also be a noun, but here it is not.

Your sentence means "since/because I have free time, become my partner" (lit. because it is free time, do partner).

Finally, I will answer your question assuming you meant to say: "what is the difference between (noun)+な and (**adjective**)+な?" (and not (**verb**)+な)

The basic difference between these two なs is that the な following an adjective is the 活用語尾 (conjugative suffix), whereas the な following a noun is the auxiliary 「だ」. Both conjugated in the 連体 form.

There is a very small difference between -na adjectives' *conjugative suffix* and the auxiliary 「だ」, which is only morphologic (meaning there is no difference in meaning): when we use an adjective in the 連体 form, what follows will always be な, for example:

> 綺麗な花
>
> 暇な時
>
> 好きな人
>
> 簡単な宿題

On the other hand, a noun has no conjugation, it acts on its own, and the following な (if there is) is independant because it is an auxiliary verb, and not a conjugation attached to the noun.

> 「厄介な」ので = adjective (because he is troublesome)
>
> 「学生」「な」ので = noun (because he is a student)

Plus, we cannot always use 「な」 (だ) after a noun, but it is okay for an adjective to be followed by な in any case.

> 学生なころ X
>
> 学生のころ O