# Explanation for 'noun + な + ので', is 'ので' still a 接続助詞 here?

Tags: relative-clauses, copula

I saw the following statement in a grammar book:

> 接続助詞 'ので' can only be placed after 用言 and 助動詞 in form of 連体形.

But in another text book it says that ので can also be placed after a noun, and then the noun is concatenated with な, e.g. 時間なので.

Is 'noun + な + ので' a special case? Is role of 'ので' here different from being placed after a verb/adj?

I searched similar questions:

1. adj. + な
   [(noun) + な versus (verb) + な](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47998/noun-%e3%81%aa-versus-verb-%e3%81%aa)
2. noun + な (but didn't cover whether in scope of 接続助詞)
   [What does "nanode" mean? What are its grammatical rules?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19591/what-does-nanode-mean-what-are-its-grammatical-rules)

Comment: な is a form of the copula, so in 'noun + な + ので' ので is preceded by a verb.

Comment: By 'conjected' did you mean 'conjugated'?

Comment: な is a (limited) 連体形 of だ.

Comment: @MathieuBouville thanks for the word suggestion, I meant 'concatenated', but chose a wrong word. I've updated the post.

Comment: Thanks both for the information. Is there a guidance when 'な' could be placed after noun?

Comment: な is used instead of だ in relative clauses. The の of nominalization is a noun, not a particle, and I suspect it gave rise to ので -- so what precedes is a relative clause. Likewise with な adjectives: な shows up before a noun.